# Error when adding a new column: requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

Tags: r, matrix

My data set contains 6 companies monthly returns which look like below (but has many more rows):

```
RMA RMB RMC     RMD     RME      RMF
NA  NA  NA      0.0099  -0.0009  NA
NA  NA  0.0395  -0.0030 0.0024   NA
```

These companies made up the portfolio. As a result, each one has its weight.

```
WRMA    <-  0.36
WRMB    <-  0.12
WRMC    <-  0.11
WRMD    <-  0.24
WRME    <-  0.15
WRMF    <-  0.02
```

What I'm trying to do is to create a column called GWMR, which =RMA x WRMA + RMB x WRMB + ... + RMF x WRMF.

Here's what I did:

```
weights <- c(WRMA,WRMB,WRMC,WRMD,WRME,WRMF)
GAA2 <- GAA
GAA2[is.na(GAA2] <- 0
GAA <- cbind(GAA, GWMR = c(GAA2 %*% weights))
```

Then I got the error message: `Error in GAA2 %*% weights : 
  requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments`

I also tried : `GAA <- cbind(GAA, GWMR = c(GAA2 %*% as.matrix(weights)))`. Still got the same error message. How may I get this right? Thanks!

Comment: Is your dataset a data.frame object? You can control it with the function `class()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your dataset as a matrix or a dataframe:

Dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = c(1:5))
```

In this case, you can add a column by:

```
df$var2 <- c(6:10)
df

  var1 var2
1    1    6
2    2    7
3    3    8
4    4    9
5    5   10
```

Matrix:

```
mx <- matrix(1:12, 4, 3)
```

For a matrix, you should:

```
mx <- cbind(mx, 13:16)
mx

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    5    9   13
[2,]    2    6   10   14
[3,]    3    7   11   15
[4,]    4    8   12   16
```

The main difference between them, in few words, is that a matrix can hold only one class of data. For example, every observation has to be `numeric` or `character` is checked with the function `class()`. More than one class cannot exist in the same matrix.

Dataframes instead have not this issue. You use data frames if columns (variables) can be expected to be of different types (numeric/character/logical etc.)

Matrices are better when you want to math operations. Data frames can be more useful if your columns have often names that you use to (es. `df$var2`)

You can convert a dataframe in a matrix, and the headers of the dataframe will be saved in the matrix. Please remember a difference: a dataframe you can do an operation (es a mean) on the second column with `mean(df$var2)`. With a matrix, you have to use indexing `mean(mx2[, 2])`.

```
mx2 <- as.matrix(df)
mx2
     var1 var2
[1,]    1    6
[2,]    2    7
[3,]    3    8
[4,]    4    9
[5,]    5   10

class(mx2)
"matrix"
```

When converting from dataframe to matrix with `as.matrix`, just be aware of **coercion**: it returns the matrix obtained by converting all the variables of your dataframe to numeric mode and then binding them together as the columns of a matrix.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. In my case, can I still convert my data set into matrix even when each column has a header? I'm fairly new to R so sorry for the basic question.

Comment: It is ok, do not worry. We are here to help each other, and in order to do that in the best way, I suggest you to check the [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), that are always useful.            Anyway, the headers of your dataframe will remain in the matrix, as you can see in the example I inserted in the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Use `as.matrix`

```
GAA <- cbind(GAA, GWMR = c(as.matrix(GAA2) %*% weights))
GAA
  RMA RMB    RMC     RMD     RME RMF     GWMR
1   0   0 0.0000  0.0099 -0.0009   0 0.002241
2   0   0 0.0395 -0.0030  0.0024   0 0.003985
```